# What do the attributes do in <script for=foo event=onmouseover>

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, inline

I read some HTML like:

```
<script for=foo event=onmouseover> ... </script>
```

Just wondering what the attributes `for=foo event=onmouseover` mean?

Comment: It's definitely not normal, browser-based JavaScript. Sounds like something for a different platform, maybe a server side language.

Comment: @Pekka – It turns out that those are IE proprietary attributes. One more word: horrible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the specifications of HTML 4.01/5 and XHTML those attributes are [invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/script). Also see the [W3C specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/script.html).

But it turns out that the attributes are proprietary to Internet Explorer, they can be found on MSDN, e.g., in [SCRIPT XHTML Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415452.aspx):

> EVENT – Specifies the name of the
>   event handler that the enclosed script
>   is bound to
>
> FOR – Specifies the name of the object
>   that the event script is bound to

Two other pages talk about these attributes with more depth: [EVENT Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533746%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [FOR Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533870%28VS.85%29.aspx). Notice that both have a note:

> **Standards Information**
>
> This property is defined in [World
>   Wide Web Consortium (W3C) Document
>   Object Model (DOM) Level 2 World Wide
>   Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/).

This is, of course, not true.

Also see [Attaching an Event Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533023(VS.85).aspx#Attaching_an_Event_H), which discusses the various methods with which an event handler can be bound to an element.

Comment: Pekka, Sorry I forgot one line of code. Just added. It seems an piece of code working on IE...

Comment: @Paul – That's not an extra line of code (in terms of Javascript), but an extra HTML line containing a normal image element. But thanks for mentioning IE, which made me look in MSDN.

Comment: You're right. it should be just "onmouseover" but without "event=" . I take back my comments.